# Tree node filtering with List<TreeNode>

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, search

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552370/tree-view-filtering-does-not-return-all-the-files) about filtering tree view and returning just first match.

I've tried to create `list<treenode>` and change the code.  Is it possible improve the below code for finding nodes and child nodes that match my criteria?

```
private List<TreeNode> FindNodeByValue(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string searchstring)
{

    // Loop through the tree node collection
    List<TreeNode> nodelist=new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        // Does the value match the search string?
        if (node.Value.ToUpper().Contains (searchstring.ToUpper()))
            // Yes it does match - return it
            nodelist.Add(node);
        //  return nodelist;
        else
        {
            // No it does not match - search any child nodes of this node
            List<TreeNode> childNode = SearchChildNodes(node, searchstring);
            // If the childNode is not null it was a match
            if (childNode != null)
                // Return the matching node
                return childNode;
        }
    }
    // If the matching node is not found return null
    return null;
}

/// <summary>
/// This method searches a node's ChildNodes collection to find a matching value
/// with the incoming search string
/// It will iteratively call itself as it drills into each nodes child nodes (if present)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parentNode">Parent node to search for a match</param>
/// <param name="searchstring">string to be matched with the Nodes Value property</param>
/// <returns>Treenode of the matching node if found.  If not found it will be null</returns>
private List<TreeNode> SearchChildNodes(TreeNode parentNode, string searchstring)
{
    List<TreeNode> nodelist2 = new List<TreeNode>();
    // Loop through the child nodes of the parentNode passed in
    foreach (TreeNode node in parentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        // Does the value match the search string?
        if (node.Value.ToUpper().Contains(searchstring.ToUpper()))
            // Yes it does match - return it
            nodelist2.Add(node);
            //return nodelist2;
            //return node;
        else
        {
            // No it does not match - recursively search any child nodes of this node
            List<TreeNode> childNode = SearchChildNodes(node, searchstring);
            // If the childNode is not null it was a match
            if (childNode != null)
                childNode.Add(node);
                // Return the matching node
                return childNode;
        }
    }
    // If the matching node is not found OR if there were no child nodes then return null
    return null;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode trnode=FindNodeByValue(TreeView1.Nodes, fieldFilterTxtBx.Text);
    if (trnode != null)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
       // TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode("Detail Engineering");
       // TreeView1.Nodes.Add(newnode);
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(trnode);
        TreeView1.ExpandAll();
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "No file found";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are trying to match multiple results, you should always check children, you are only doing that if a node does not match which i believe is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Currently you do not search sub nodes it a matching parent is found. This code fixes that problem and also simplifies the code by removing the unnecessary `SearchChildNodes` function. 
If you only care about the first match use `var node = FindNodeByValue(TreeView1.Nodes, fieldFilterTxtBx.Text).FirstOrDefault();`

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> FindNodeByValue(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string searchstring)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        if (node.Value.IndexOf(searchstring, 
              StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            yield return node;
        else
        {
            foreach (var subNode in FindNodeByValue(node.ChildNodes, searchstring))
                yield return subNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that there will be no out of stack (I'm pretty sure JIT wouldn't be able to optimize out recursive calls through several helper objects built for implementing `IEnumerable`). Here is small modifications to version of @Magnus:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> SearchNodesByValue(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string searchstring)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(nodes.GetEnumerator());
    try
    {
        do
        {
            var frame = stack.Peek();
            var it = frame.Peek();
            if (!it.MoveNext())
            {
                frame.Pop().Dispose();
                continue;
            }
            var node = it.Current;
            if (node.Value.Contains(searchstring)) yield return node;
            else frame.Push(node.ChildNodes.GetEnumerator());
        } while(stack.Count > 0);
    }
    finally
    {
        // cleanup enumerators
        while(stack.Count > 0) stack.Pop().Dispose();
    }
}
```